# Actual file size exceeds maxsize

Tags: sql-server, filesize

I found out that one of our databases has a file that is larger than the defined max. size, see picture below.

Never seen this before and I cannot find similar cases on the internet.

Database seems to be working fine, but I think this needs fixing.

We're running SQL Server 2012 (SP3-CU10) (yes, I know... they're working on it)

Any ideas?

[image: output of sp_helpfile]

Comment: [sp_helpfile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helpfile-transact-sql) was a wrapper for the SQL Server 2000 system table, [sys.sysfiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysfiles-transact-sql), which is deprecated. Do you get the same result from [sys.database_files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-files-transact-sql)? (Note that `size` and `maxsize` here are measured in 8 KiB pages.)

Comment: Thanks, but BOL does not qualify sp_helpfile as deprecated: **Applies to: SQL Server (all supported versions)**
In fact I believe SSMS still uses it to display info.
Anyway, sys.database_files gives the same image: size = 80640000, maxsize = 72089600

Comment: *"Applies to: SQL Server (all supported versions)"* Doesn't mean not deprecated, @HansvanDam , it means that it is available in all versions. [ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql) states *"Applies to: SQL Server (all supported versions)"*, but all 3 have been deprecated since **2005** (17 years).

Comment: Deprecated or not, the info is correct Larnu.
The topic is that the file is larger than maxsize so if you can help with that, please!